# Period of a trigonometric function

Tags: periodic-functions

Is the function $\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{\cos(x)}$ periodic? If that is the case, what are the steps to calculate the period?

Comment: It is clearly periodic, since $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$.

Comment: Why do you say it is not elementary? It looks like an elementary function to me. But what are you expecting its domain to be. As a function of a real variable it is not defined when $\sin(x)$ is negative. If you want to be a function of a complex variable, then you need to explain where you are putting the branch cut in $\sqrt{\cdot}$.

Comment: The function is not defined for $(\pi+2k\pi,2\pi+2k\pi), k \in \Bbb Z$. For the domain of definition the function is periodic where it seems to resemble the tangent.

Comment: @RobArthan You are right, the function is elementary. I was a bit confused about the definition of "elementary function". I expect its domain to be a subset of real numbers, specifically the domain that WindSoul mentioned : $(2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi), k \in \mathbb{Z}$